# How to pass db2 values to jQuery grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, db2

I have a db2 table with certain columns. I have a stored procedure for select all table

Can anybody tell me  how to use this stored procedure to fill the json grid.

Using Asp.net mvc control.

Comment: Umm... start with reading the documentation

Comment: which documentatin should I go with..thanks if you have any sample code please let me know..

Comment: There are a lot of components between JSON-formatted data on the front end and stored procedures on the back end.  Can you narrow your question?  Have you looked at the multiple resources at the bottom of http://json.org/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [jQuery Grid Plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) it comes with more features then you can imagine for a js-grid.

Try the demos and check if it is to your liking. Then check the documentation to find out how to fill the grid with json data.